# How to customize TFS email notifications

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to add alert name to Email footer.
But i don't know how to get alert name in TeamFoundation.xls
Can anybody help me with it?

TFS Version is 14.102.25423.0
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-customize-alerts#customize-the-format-for-tfs-email-alerts

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9wKm.png)

Comment: You can also consider using a specialized tools like [CatLight status notifier](https://catlight.io) to get notifications about work item changes. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228776/alert-when-tfs-team-query-results-change/42306307#42306307

Comment: After go through both the webpage with F12 and sql server data base, couldn't find the related parameter of that name. How did you get the alert ID? But one thing  certain the name is called **template name**  and  corresponding to the ID one by one.