# Alert when TFS team query results change

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create a TFS alert that notifies the user when the results of a certain query has changed?!

Example:

- I have a query which finds 10 work items as a result
- one of those work items has changed that it does not fulfill this query anymore (query results should be 9).

I would like a notification telling me that the results of the query has changed (also referring to the work item that has changed)

The other way around should be also valid, that a work item was modified to fulfill the query (query results should be 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [CatLight status notifier](https://catlight.io). It will show a notification on the desktop new work item matches the query or when this work item changes.

[image: CatLight Work item Query changed alert]

In addition, if you miss that notification, you can always see what changed on the dashboard:

[image: CatLight work item changes on the dashboard]

The app currently will not notify you when work item stops matching the query, but you can create an inverse query to catch such changes.

Comment: Thanks Alex!, but this doesn't seem to work with TFS. In configuration I can only see Builds, not work items, which means I cannot choose a query. Do you have any idea why this is not working?! (I'm using VS 2015)

Comment: Catlight works with TFS 2015/2017 and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). Unfortunately, I use TFS 2013.

Comment: Yep, work items appear [only for TFS 2015 and newer](http://catlight.helprace.com/i183-i-m-able-to-log-in-and-see-builds-but-not-work-items-in-tfs-anyone-know-why-or-how-to-set-up-work-items). You can give it another try if your TFS server gets upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this directly.

You may want to try creating a Notification, but you are going to struggle if your query is complicated.

https://[youraccount].visualstudio.com/_notifications